# Do I need a ground rod in addition to a pipe? Subpanel in separate structure

Tags: electrical-panel, grounding

The scenario: detached garage with a subpanel supplied by a 30a 240v feeder from the house, with two hots, neutral, and EGC.  There is also an Ethernet cable from the house to the garage, carrying a phone line, but technically this could be  "another metallic path" between the buildings.

The neutrals and EGC are *not* bonded at the subpanel.  EGC at the subpanel is connected to a 1" iron pipe, which goes into the ground and runs horizontally about 30 feet, 18" deep, terminating underground at nothing. (No idea what it was for.)

The questions: do I need a ground rod at the garage, in addition to this pipe?  Or is the pipe + EGC from the house sufficient? If I do need a rod, does it need to be 6+ feet away from the pipe?

Comment: I'm assuming the garage is on a concrete slab; I don't suppose you have a metal rod sticking up anywhere from the slab, do you? Sometimes people have the foresight to install those to serve as electrodes for grounding in detached structures.

Comment: @TylerH, I want to say "no, there is not" but I suppose I should go look again just to be sure.  I really don't think there is.

Comment: What Tyler is referring to is rebar imbedded in concrete as a Ufer ground. It is a very effective grounding electrode. The code requires 20' minimum of #4 or larger bar in the concrete, which is likely if exposed, but hard to prove to an inspector after the pour.

Comment: I imagine if the slab is large enough, you could argue that there'd have to be that much rebar in it, or otherwise it would be very weak and wouldn't work as a foundation.  The fact that it's not falling apart after being there a number of years would be evidence of proper rebar inside.  YMMV, of course.

Comment: @NateS.Agreed :), was just intended as a warning that with some inspectors if they can't see it then it doesn't exist.

Comment: @NoSparksPlease understood on all counts - I'll double-check after work but I really don't think there's a piece of rebar poking out.  I also understand that if it IS there, there's really no way to tell what's on the other end of it - whether three more inches of rebar, or 20 more feet.  The floor itself has been there for 22 years, in a northern climate, with nary a crack to be found, so it definitely has steel of some kind in it... but understood and agreed, if the inspector can't see it, it ain't there.

Answer (score 1):

The NEC requires "grounding electrode(s)", a ground rod is one acceptable electrode. All electrodes that are present are required to be bonded to the service.

To qualify as a service electrode NEC 250.52(A)(5) allows pipe or conduit 8' long, 3/4" min diameter, with a corrosive resistant coating to be used as an electrode.  250.53 requires it be driven to a depth of 8' unless hitting rock bottom, then it can be driven at a 45 degree angle or buried in a trench a minimum 30" deep. Your pipe horizontally buried 18" deep in a trench for convenience it is quite likely to be rejected by the local AHJ. 250.53 also specifies plate, pipe, and rod spacing to be at least 6'.

The connector to the pipe must be NRTL (UL,CSA,MET) *Listed* for the purpose.

There is also some disagreement about how many electrodes you need, using only a plate, rod, or pipe electrode at a service requires a supplemental electrode. Some jurisdictions allow a single plate, rod, or pipe electrode at an accessory building. I think the argument for the code allowing that is weak, although the logic of a 4th rod electrode could be understandably be argued redundant.

Comment: To clarify - that pipe was put in the ground by a previous owner, presumably to run water out to where his pool used to be.  The connector to the pipe is a proper grounding clamp, listed for the purpose.  In a practical sense, I think the pipe is better than having no ground electrode at all - which is how I found it, along with bonded grounds & neutrals in the subpanel - but the rules is the rules, and it sounds like I need to abandon the pipe and sink a proper ground electrode in the dirt instead.

Comment: If I was driving two rods and the pipe wasn't between them I might not disconnect the pipe. It is an electrode, just not installed in such a way to satisfy the requirements for insuring enough effect required by code. It could be argued that 250.50 requires it to be bonded if it enters the building even if not used.

Comment: Yeah don't disconnect the pipe -- you're required to bond it too, and there's no downside to leaving it.  Just add a ground rod in addition.

Comment: Fair enough.  Thanks all!

Answer (score 1):

### You can drive rods if you wish, but they aren't *essential*

NEC 250.52 sets out eight permissible categories of grounding electrodes, of which your mystery-pipe can fall into three.  It could be considered an (abandoned) water line in the vein of 250.52(A)(1), which would make it a legal electrode albeit one that requires supplemental rods.  However, the fact that it was abandoned weighs against that option.  It's not a made (driven) pipe electrode under 250.52(A)(5) either since it's not driven/laid deep enough.

This leaves 250.52(A)(8) for "other local metal underground systems or structures".  This is used for miscellaneous piping systems, buried metal tanks, metal well casings that aren't connected to the water system by metallic paths, and other such things that aren't covered by any other Code section.  Note that a 250.52(A)(8) electrode isn't required to be supplemented by made electrodes, *unlike* a 250.52(A)(1) water pipe electrode.  This is because the supplementing rules are designed to mitigate against a plumber replacing a damaged water service with plastic, thus removing the water line from service as an electrode.  This hazard doesn't exist for an ex-water-line that's been abandoned in place, so you're free to leave the pipe in service as an electrode, and drive or not drive supplemental rods as you wish.